# Trying to create a class but I'm not getting output for my c# application that uses the class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm new and am unable to get any output for my function. Any help would be appreciated. Here I'm trying to create an employee object and have it output a name and salary through get and set functions.

The second part of my code are the setters and getters. I'm not sure what is wrong because I am not getting any build errors from visual studio.

```
// create new employee object
employee emp1 = new employee();

Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
var emp1nm = Console.ReadLine();
emp1.setName(emp1nm);

Console.WriteLine("What is your hourly rate?");
var emp1rate = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
emp1.setRate(emp1rate);

Console.WriteLine("How many hours did you work?");
var emp1hr = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
emp1.setHR(emp1hr);

string employeeName = emp1.getName();
double employeeSalary = emp1.getSalaryAmount();

Console.WriteLine("Employee Name:   ", employeeName);
Console.WriteLine("Salary:          ", employeeSalary);
```

Class for this issue with output

```
public class employee
{
    public string nm; // name
    public string et; // employee type
    public double samt; // salary amount
    public double hr;
    public double rate;

    const double tax = 0.34; // total taxes and contributions

    public employee()
    {
        nm = "";
        et = "";
        samt = 0;
        hr = 0;
        rate = 0;
    }
    public void setName(string name)
    {
        nm = name;
    }
    public string getName()
    {
        return nm;
    }
    public void setRate(double hourlyRate)
    {
        rate = hourlyRate;
    }
    public double getRate()
    {
        return rate;
    }
    public void setHR(double hours)
    {
        hr = hours;
    }
    public double getHR()
    {
        return hr;
    }
    // get salary amount
    public double getSalaryAmount()
    {
        return samt * tax;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any errors or warnings or exceptions or example of what it *does* do?

Comment: no, when I press f6 to build it in visual studio 2015, I get no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is here with the `Console.WriteLine` you forgot to add placeholder, Please replace the following lines

```
Console.WriteLine("Employee Name:   ", employeeName);
Console.WriteLine("Salary:          ", employeeSalary);
```

With this lines:

```
Console.WriteLine("Employee Name : {0}", employeeName);
Console.WriteLine("Salary        : {0}", employeeSalary);
```

Or Like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Employee Name : " + employeeName);
Console.WriteLine("Salary        : " + employeeSalary);
```

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to work. For whatever reason, I thought concatenating those two statements only required a comma.

Comment: @randy-x-lee Comma can't  be used for concatenating two strings, we should either use `+` or a placeholder Like the above example. You can mark it as accepted if it really helps you to solve the issues.